# how to create a security group with dynamic IP address on amazon web service

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

i need to run an instance and access with my ip address..but the problem is that myISP changes my IP adress every day.plz help me how do i create a security group so that my instance remains accessible even if my ip changes....

thanks in advance..

Comment: I made an [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-ip) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to restrict AWS security group to your dynamic IP address for SSH.

You can write a cronjob to regularly repeat the steps below:

1. Fetch external IP address (e.g. http://checkip.amazonaws.com/)
2. Fetch security group details using AWS SDK
3. Loop through all security rules, check for port `22`
4. If IP address mismatches that from step 1, update it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a security group with port 22 ingress access from your current ip.
2. Add a Tag to the security group with the key `ssh-from-my-ip` and the value `true`
3. Whenever your IP changes run this script (or run it periodically via `cron`)

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# This script makes it easier to maintain security groups that allow SSH access
# from a computer with a dynamic IP, such as a computer on a home network or ISP.
#
# Using the script will allow you to SSH to an EC2 without having to allow
# access to the whole world (0.0.0.0/0). If you run this script whenever your IP
# changes then the security groups in your account specified by your AWS profile
# will be updated.
#
# The script will find any security groups for your current profile that are
# tagged with a Tag with a Key of "ssh-from-my-ip" and a case insensitive value
# of "true" or "yes".
#
# For each security group found it will revoke any existing tcp ingress on
# port 22 and authorize ingress on port 22 for your current IP.
#
# Dependencies - AWS CLI and jq


# need my current ip
MY_IP=$(curl --silent https://checkip.amazonaws.com)
echo "Your IP is ${MY_IP}"

# need security group id(s) and existing CIDR for the SG
pairs=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups | aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq -c '.SecurityGroups[]? | select( (.Tags[]? | select(.Key == "ssh-from-my-ip") | .Value | test("true|yes"; "i"))) | if .IpPermissions | length == 0 then {sg: .GroupId, cidr: null } else {sg: .GroupId, cidr: .IpPermissions[].IpRanges[].CidrIp} end')

for p in $pairs
do
  SG=$(echo "$p" | jq -r '.sg')
  OLD_CIDR=$(echo "$p" | jq -r '.cidr')

  echo "Updating security group ${SG}"
  if [[ $OLD_CIDR != 'null' ]]
  then
    echo "Revoking ingress permission for ${OLD_CIDR} in security group ${SG}"
    # remove the existing ingress permission
    aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
        --group-id "${SG}" \
        --protocol tcp \
        --port 22 \
        --cidr "${OLD_CIDR}"
  fi

  # authorize my new IP CIDR
  NEW_CIDR="${MY_IP}"/32
  echo "Authorizing ingress permission for ${NEW_CIDR} in security group ${SG}"
  aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id "${SG}" --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 22, "ToPort": 22, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "'"${NEW_CIDR}"'", "Description": "Rule0"}]}]'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# User specific data:
SECURITY_GROUP_NAME="" # Setup here your group name
REGION=${1:-"us-east-1"} # Change default region if needed


USER=`aws iam get-user --query "User.UserName" | tr -d '"'`
RULE_DESCRIPTION='DynamicIP'$USER
echo 'User: '$RULE_DESCRIPTION', Region: '$REGION', Security group: '$SECURITY_GROUP_NAME

checkip () {
    OLD_CIDR_IP=`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region $REGION --query "SecurityGroups[?GroupName=='$SECURITY_GROUP_NAME'].IpPermissions[*].IpRanges[?Description=='$RULE_DESCRIPTION'].CidrIp" --output text`
    NEW_IP=`curl -s http://checkip.amazonaws.com`
    NEW_CIDR_IP=$NEW_IP'/32'

    if [[ $OLD_CIDR_IP != "" ]] && [[ $OLD_CIDR_IP != $NEW_CIDR_IP ]]; then
        echo "Revoking $OLD_CIDR_IP"
        aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --region $REGION --group-name $SECURITY_GROUP_NAME --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $OLD_CIDR_IP --output text >> /dev/null
    fi

    if [[ $NEW_IP != "" ]] && [[ $OLD_CIDR_IP != $NEW_CIDR_IP ]]; then
        echo "Setting up new ip $NEW_IP"
        aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --region $REGION --group-name $SECURITY_GROUP_NAME --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 22, "ToPort": 22, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "'$NEW_CIDR_IP'", "Description": "'$RULE_DESCRIPTION'"}]}]'
    fi

    sleep 30
    checkip
}

checkip
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a Source CIDR of 0.0.0.0/0 to allow universal access.

You could restrict it to your ISP's address space by looking up their allocations or just monitoring what IP addresses you end up with.

To do it properly and restrict access to a single IP dynamic address you could write an application that monitors your public IP address and when it changes call the [EC2 API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/) AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress method and delete the old address with RevokeSecurityGroupIngress.

Comment: wouldnt this be a security issue to open it up to 0.0.0.0/0 ?

Comment: Depends. Your vm's OS could be doing the fire walling.

Comment: The correct API would be AuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress, if you wanted to add a CIDR to the db security group.